# Using jQuery to set onkeypress attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I need to use an external script to set the `onkeypress` attribute of an input with a unique `id`. I tried to use `$j('#numret').attr('onkeypress', 'calc();');`, but this code did not work. Is there a way to alter this attribute externally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach event listener:

```
$j('#req').keypress(calc);
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, unfortunately. I've tried lots of different variations, but I'm still new to Javascript. [This is a simplified example of my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/TD93h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#req").keypress(function(event){
   calc();
});
```